# linkify urls in  templates-nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperlink

Think my query was clear from the title itself. How can I link url strings with href attributes while rendering in ejs templates? Do any helpers exist for this task? I thought of converting urls to strings right along with their href attributes and then send them to templates but I guess they will then be escaped while rendering.

Even though I am using ejs for views..I wanna change the template engine if any other has this linking facility.

Update:

suppose this is the render function

```
return res.render("polo", {
                    title: "Posters",
                    has_next:false,
                    posters:posters,
                    offset:0
                });
```

and here is the view

```
<% for (var i=0;i<posters.length;i++) { %>

                <div id="<%=posters[i]._id %>" class="newstitle">

                <p>
                <%=posters[i].body %>
            </p>
            </div>

<% }; %>
```

Now if posters[1].body="Hello this is a good site. www.google.com" .Similarly every other element in poster array is some text which contains some urls.
when posters[i].body is rendered i want the urls like "google.com" in above example to be linked. 
I cant use <%= url %> because I dont know where exactly the url is inside poster.body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output to an href attribute without escaping, then, you can use `<a href="<%- yourvar %>">the link.</a>` and it won't escape.

(Note, the use of the hyphen instead of the equal sign.)

**Edit**

OP asked how to only display the link when the url is defined.

```
<% if (typeof yourvar != 'undefined' && yourvar !== null) { %>
  <a href="<%- yourvar %>">the link</a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: suppose i have a text which may or may not contain a url then I cant apply this method since I dont know beforehand where the url is there in the text's body. How should I do it then?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you don't want to show any links, whatsoever, whenever there the text's body is not defined?

Comment: @KamalReddy, I have made an update to the answer. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Please look at the update I have made to the question. I think I have made the question clear this time.